# Override in the widget attributes the max_length set on the Model

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

In the `Model` I set the maxlength of the field:

```
short_description = models.CharField(max_length=405)
```

In the `ModelForm` in the widget attributes I set minlength an maxlength:

```
class ItemModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name', 'short_description', 'description']
    widgets = {
            'name': TextInputWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name*'}),
        'short_description': TextareaWidget(attrs={'minlength': 200, 'maxlength': 400})
```

}

The issue in the HTML the minlegth is from the widget, but maxlength is still taken from the model(405 instead of 400).

I want the widget attribute to overwrite the model attribute.

Comment: post your full modelform

Comment: @Exprator it is a normal ModelForm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `widgets` property in the Meta class modify only, well, the widgets, not the field attributes itself. What you have to do is redefine your model form field.

```
class ItemModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    short_description = forms.CharField(max_length=400, min_length=200, widget=TextareaWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name', 'short_description', 'description']
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInputWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name*'}),
        }
```

Comment: actually it added minlenght (but this didn't existed on the model)

Comment: But you added the minlength youself in your code snippet, I just replicated what you had: `'short_description': TextareaWidget(attrs={'minlength': 200, 'maxlength': 400}) `. If you don't need the `min_length`, just remove it: `short_description = forms.CharField(max_length=400, widget=TextareaWidget())`

Answer (score 1):

```
class ItemModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    short_description = forms.CharField(
        max_length = 400,
        min_length = 200,
        widget=forms.Textarea(
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name', 'short_description', 'description']
        widgets = {
        'name': TextInputWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name*'}),
        }
```